# tinyMCE in angular6 application not making font bold

Tags: angular, tinymce

I am new to StackOverflow, please excuse me for any typos.

Well, I am developing angular 6 application therein I am having tinyMCE version 5 editor confgured as below:

```
  tinymce.init({
      selector: '.TinyMCE',
      mode: 'exact',
      height: 150,
      menubar: false,
      theme: 'silver',
      statusbar: false,
      plugins: 'placeholder',
      content_style:
        '#tinymce-body { min-height: 0px; } .mce-content-body { color: rgba(101, 99, 93, 1); overflow-x: hidden !important; }',
      body_id: 'tinymce-body',
      toolbar: 'bold underline italic addAttachment',
      valid_elements: 'strong/b,i/italic,p,br',
      inline_styles: false,
      formats: {
        underline: { inline: 'u', exact: true },
        italic: { inline: 'i', exact: true },
        bold: { inline: 'b', exact: true }
        },
      elements: this.elementID,
      setup: this.tinyMCESetup.bind(this),
      //  setup: this.getSetup,
    });
```

On setup function...

```
 tinyMCESetup(ed) {
    ed.on('keyup', this.tinyMCEOnKeyup.bind(this));
    this.editor = ed;
    //starts  here
    ed.ui.registry.addButton('Bold', {
      text: '',
      onAction: () => {
        ed.execCommand('Bold');
        return false;
      }
    });

  }
```

However, when I send content to the after selecting text inside editor and making them bold does not work, I mean when I debug my application it simply sends the text as.

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

However I am expecting it to have

```
<p><strong>Hello</strong></p>
```

Attachced is the screenshot of my tinyMCE editor embedded in angular 6 chat application.

[tinyMCE picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylc9P.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing below init property of tinymce.

```
 schema:'html5',
formats: {

        underline: { inline: 'u', exact: true },
        italic: { inline: 'em', exact: true },
        bold: { inline: 'b', exact: true }
        }
```

this helped me to create bold , italic and underline.

Hope this helps to someone who needs it.

Thanks